# Saving input data doesn't save when clicked the edit button

Tags: reactjs, react-native

There are these three states which I have right now. When I want to edit the address, it doesn't save immediately. It shows the edited input when again go back from movit driver page to the personal details page.

**This is the movit driver page**
[image: This is the movit driver page]

**This is the personal details**
[image: This is the personal details]

**This is the edit page**
[image: This is the edit page]

There might be some problem with the async storage which shows the edited input when gone back from the driver page.

```js
**Address.js**
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      address: '',
      userToken: null
    }
  }
  
  async componentWillMount() {
    try {
      let value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userData')
      let userDetails = JSON.parse(value)
      console.log('userDetails 2: ', userDetails)
      if (userDetails !== null) {
        this.setState({
          address: userDetails.address,
          userToken: userDetails.token
        })
      }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
  }

  saveAddressEdit = (fieldName, fieldValue) => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem(fieldName, fieldValue)
  
    let {userToken} = this.state
  
    var formData = new FormData()
    formData.append(fieldName, fieldValue)
  
    fetch('MyURL', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'X-API-KEY': 'myApiKey',
        'Authorization': userToken
      },
      body: formData
    }).then(function (response) {
       console.log(response)
       let data = JSON.parse(response._bodyText)
       Alert.alert(data.message)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
    .done()
  }

  render() {
    const {address} = this.state

    return (
      <Container>
        <Content style={{marginHorizontal:20}}>
          <Item style={{marginVertical:40}}>
            <Input placeholder=" Type your Address:" 
              onChangeText={(address) => this.setState({address})}
              value={address}
            />
          </Item>
           <Button full danger  onPress={()=>this.saveAddressEdit('address', address)} style={{backgroundColor:'#ff0000'}}>
                <Text style={{color: '#ffffff'}}>Update Address</Text>
              </Button>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the **address.js** code for editing. The solution i need is like i want to show immediately the edited input. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you are not passing the state when clicking the button. Change onPress function call to

```
onPress={()=>this.saveAddressEdit('address', this.state.address)}
```

also, change the TextInput value

value={this.state.address}

and don't try to use the same name as the constant inside the onTextChange Callback

So your final render function is

```
render() {

    return (
      <Container>
        <Content style={{marginHorizontal:20}}>
          <Item style={{marginVertical:40}}>
            <Input placeholder=" Type your Address:" 
              onChangeText={(address) => this.setState({address:address})}
              value={this.state.address}
            />
          </Item>
           <Button full danger  onPress={()=>this.saveAddressEdit('address', this.state.address)} style={{backgroundColor:'#ff0000'}}>
                <Text style={{color: '#ffffff'}}>Update Address</Text>
              </Button>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I already destructure in a render() method like this :  

const {address} = this.state

Comment: Have you replaced your code with the above? The problem may be due to the use of same name for variables.